# jQuery clock does not work in JSF2.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, jsf-2.2

I am trying to display time and date in my JSF page and I put the CSS and script each of them in specific folder that shown below but it does not work. While it is work well using HTML. Can you help me please.

```
    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css"   />
    <h:outputScript name="js/clock.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

</h:head>
<h:body>
 <div class="container">
                <div class="clock">
                    <h:panelGroup id="Date">  </h:panelGroup>
                            <ul>
                                 <li id="thehours"> </li>
                                 <li id="thepoint">:</li>
                                 <li id="themin"> </li>
                                 <li id="thepoint">:</li>
                                 <li id="thesec"> </li>
                            </ul>   
</div>
</div>
</h:body>
```

`

Comment: For starters, if anything appears to be failing in client side, press F12 and check console for clues. Surely you should be seeing some JS errors which are in turn usually good search keywords for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `clock.js` is dependent on `jQuery.js` it can't be loaded before `jQuery.js`. You should be seeing errors in your browser console from this

Switch the order of loading

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>    
<h:outputScript name="js/clock.js" />
```

If `clock.js` is a plugin that requires being initialized you would also need to add that initialization code after both of the library dependencies